# SP 2010 and Internet Explorer 11 Release Preview issue

Tags: 2010, internet-explorer

I have recently installed IE 11 Release Preview and having some really big issues with it since. For instance, the Edit Web Part drop down arrow is significantly smaller, almost hard to see, cannot be clicked, and there is no "Connections" option. Furthermore, in CA, when I try to edit a User profile under Manage User Profiles, a drop down is missing. These issues are really annoying, and make things really hard to work.

I understand that this is just a Preview, but is this just my case or another MS inconsistency with products and has someone found a (at least temporary) workaround without involving uninstalling IE 11?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I`ve tried to put the site under Compatibility View, and it works, but this should not work like this for every user. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE has a history of not working correctly with SharePoint. IE9 and WSS3 were a disaster. SP2010 is way behind what modern browsers can do. I would not expect anything in SP 2010 to work, UNLESS turning on compatibility view. That's what it's for. Compatibility with older technology. Suggestion: Stick to IE8. It works best with SP 2010.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 2 addressed some issues with IE10 compatability - updating may also help with IE11.

Comment: Already on Service Pack 2, and it was working okay on IE10, even without Compatibility View. I think it's like teylyn said, this is just "outdated" technology for modern browsers. Shame MS didn't run some SP tests with the IE11. Thanks for the response anyway :)